# What's the term for bank microdeposit, small test deposits that one bank sends to another to verify the second account's information and ownership?

Tags: translation

"micro + deposit"  can be literally translated as 小額 + 存款, but this doesn't capture the meanings below.

1. [How do I verify my bank with Microdeposits? – Wealthsimple help center](https://help.wealthsimple.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011378868-How-do-I-verify-my-bank-with-Microdeposits-)

> ## How do I verify my bank with Microdeposits?
>
> When you opt to verify your bank with microdeposits, we'll send two deposits between 0.01 and 0.99 to your bank account. You should expect to see these in your bank account within 2-3 days after the date of the request.
>
> To finish opening your account, please check to see that you have received the deposits and input both amounts on your Wealthsimple homepage. Once you've entered the correct amounts, your bank will be approved and any pending deposits from the bank account will be processed.

2. [Verify bank account with test deposit - G Suite Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1229546?hl=en)

> When you add a bank account to your Google billing account, we can’t debit payments from the account until we verify it’s yours. If your bank account has a billing address in the U.S. or a supported European country, Google makes a small test deposit into the account. Enter the same amount in your Google billing account so that we know that your account is valid and that you can access it.

3. [What are microdeposits? | TransferWise Help Centre](https://transferwise.com/help/articles/2743360/how-to-use-microdeposits)

> ### What are microdeposits?
>
> If you're making a transfer from the US, and you set up an ACH bank debit for your USD transfer, we need to verify that your bank account belongs to you. If we're unable to do this with your bank login details, we might be able to verify you with microdeposits.
>
> This means we'll send two small amounts (between 0.01-0.99 USD) to your account, which will appear on your bank statement. It can take up to 2 business days for these to arrive.
>
> As soon as you see them, you can enter them on your transfer page, and this will immediately verify your account. You can only do this on the website, not the app.

4. [How does the micro-deposit (bank linking) process work? – Wealthfront Support](https://support.wealthfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/215265043-How-does-the-micro-deposit-bank-linking-process-work-)

> If your bank does not support electronic login verification, we have to verify the account information via a "micro deposit" process.
>
> The micro-deposits are two small test deposits sent to your bank account to verify that we have the correct bank account information for you. The micro deposits usually arrive in 1-2 business days (you can see them in your bank account's transaction history).
>
> You can then log back into Wealthfront and enter these amounts to set up your ACH relationship. To enter the amounts, simply go to your "settings" tab and look under "MY ACCOUNTS". See below for a screenshot of where to confirm the two deposits:

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, the literal meaning of  'micro-deposit' (微額存款) doesn't explain the actual function of it in English or Chinese. I would say translate 'micro-deposit' literally as 微額存款 is acceptable. Since people who know what 'micro-deposit' is, would also understand what 微額存款 mean. And people who don't know what 'micro-deposit' is, would need an explanation for 微額存款 just like they would need an explanation for 'micro-deposit'

If the translator worry about Chinese speakers who never heard of 'micro-deposit' will not understand what 微存款 mean, he might as well describe it in the name and write "戶口認證用微額存款" (Micro-deposit for account verification)